# SSIS Flat File Source 1000 records will then need to be merged into one record line

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a flat file source that contains 1000 records which will then be need to merged into one record line for an eventual push through a import column to be inserted into an image field in a destination table.  How does one combine records from a flat file into one record line?  Link below is pic of the data flow task of the flat file.
https://1drv.ms/i/s!AsAeRbH-asQpeyv13bebAXOuuNE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS load a .csv file into one record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39754642/ssis-load-a-csv-file-into-one-record)

Comment: You should edit your original question, not post a new version of it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this could be as follow:

1. Send the data to a staging table in SQL Server
2. Use EXECUTE SQL Task to transform the data with FOR XML clause

For example:

```
 SELECT (STUFF((
            SELECT 'DELIMITER ' + COLUMN
            FROM TABLE

            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 2, '')
        )
```

PS:

- TABLE= Table where the data will be loaded
- COLUMN= Column where the data is contained
- DELIMITER= comma, tab or punctuation of choice to separate each row